# Karma error: require is not defined

Tags: ember.js, qunit, karma-runner

I use karma with qunit for test an emberjs application. The karma.conf.js file have this piece of code for link my project libraries

```
files: [
    "app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js",
    "app/bower_components/mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js",
    "app/bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js",
    "app/bower_components/ember/ember.js",
    "app/bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js",
    "app/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js",
    "app/scripts/app.js",
    "tests/test.js"
],
```

and my app.js is this:

```
var MyApp = window.MyApp = Ember.Application.create();

require('scripts/controllers/*');
require('scripts/store');
require('scripts/models/*');
require('scripts/routes/*');
require('scripts/components/*');
require('scripts/views/*');
require('scripts/router');
```

but when i start karma with the config file, it report this error

```
Firefox 30.0.0 (Ubuntu) ERROR
ReferenceError: require is not defined at ~/myApp/app/scripts/app.js:4
```

I've tried to change the order of the libraries in the karma.conf file but doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Try installing requirejs and including it in the files section of **karma.conf.js**.

```
npm install requirejs
```

Running this command will create a **node_modules** folder, if one doesn't already exist. RequireJS will be probably be in:

```
node_modules/requirejs/require.js
```

So, you can try editing your files section like this:

```
files: [
    "node_modules/requirejs/require.js",
    ...
]
```